# How to get specific registry key subkey

Tags: c#, registry, nic

Anybody knows, how can get programmatically get subkey like 0001 , 0002 , or 0005 and so on ?
From

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

In these keys 0001 , 0002 ... gas stored information about  NIC cards !

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` / `.RegistryKey` classes.
Example:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
...
//Where CardInformation is some data structure to hold the information.

public static IEnumerable<CardInformation> GetCardInformation()
{
    string cardsKeyAddress =  "\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}";
    RegistryKey cardsKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(cardsKeyAddress);
    string[] cardNumbers = cardsKey.GetSubKeyNames();

    foreach(string n in cardNumbers)
        yield return LoadCardInformation(cardsKeyAddress+"\\"+n);
}
static CardInformation LoadCardInformation(string key)
{
    //Get whatever values from the key to return
    CardInfomation info = new CardInformation();
    info.Name = Registry.GetValue(key, "Name", "Unnamed");
    return info;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`and the same classes to do that. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2hs0tae%28v=vs.71%29)